# Creating Play Framework Module: IDE settings and dependency on another play module

Tags: playframework

I'm creating a Play module for the first time.  Would I be correct in saying that neither commands:

```
play idealize
play eclipsify
```

can be used to generate IDE settings files for modules meaning that you just have to set things up manually?

Also, if I wanted to write a module that depended on another existing Play module, how would I build the module successfully?

So for example, if my module was called `somemodule` and I added a dependency on the existing Play PDF module, then my dependencies.yml would look like this:

```
self: play -> somemodule 0.1

require:
    - play
    - play -> pdf 0.9
```

Then I could run `play dependencies` and start writing some code in the `src` folder.  When I go to build the module:

```
play build-module
```

it does not seem to recognize the fact that I am depending on the PDF module and I get a bunch of compilation errors since it cannot see the PDF class files.  Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/dependency#Localrepositories

Comment: Does that mean when you create a custom Play module, all dependencies will always be packaged up with your module? so if my module depended on the play PDF module, then my module will be a zip file that contains all the jars found in the PDF module?  I was under the impression that Play would use the custom module's dependencies.yml to figure out what additional jars it needed to pull down to make the custom module work.  Would someone be able to confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to update the `build.xml` (that gets generated for you when you create your Play module) to specify an additional fileset in the project's classpath.  So using my example in the OP, the you could add the following to get the build to work:

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    ...
    <fileset dir="modules">
        <include name="**/lib/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This will add all jars in the lib directory of all modules that get put into your module's project after resolving its dependencies (using `play deps`)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use eclipsify on your module juste create an empty application.conf file with one line

```
application.name=mymodule
```

A module can depends on other modules, use eclipsify an see in your ide if your class compile or not

Comment: thanks Seb, that looks to have solve the first part of the problem. It definitely compiles in the IDE however when running 'play build-module', it still has compilation errors because it can't see the pdf module.  Only other way around it is to copy the PDF jar libraries into my module's 'lib' directory, but obviously that is not ideal.